# HI,I ran into a booting problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So I wanted to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PK7gWIkAY7s
The problem I got was, after I restarted pc when prompted by Ubuntu installer.
I of course loaded into grub ,but Windows 8 isn’t there only Ubuntu.(on Ubuntu now)
This is my pc: http://www.pcworld.com/product/1179403/alienware-x51-mini-system-desktop.html

I have my Windows 8 disk, but I need to know what went wrong and how to fix it and make it so I can choose to boot Windows 8 or Ubuntu. When I got to Ubuntu home I see my Windows 8 partition as device.

Thx you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the GRUB configuration file once. It may be located in /boot/grub/ [or] etc/default/grub/ by default. "grub.cfg" file can be opened by any text editor. See if there is any Windows 8 entry in this file normally at the end of all entrys.

Comment: No there is nothing about windows 8

Comment: I think grub updating process at last while installing Ubuntu didn't go well. Try updating grub once again. type in terminal "sudo update-grub" without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your issue would be to configure grub by first installing grub-customizer.

In Ubuntu, open a terminal window with ctrl+alt+t and enter the following to install grub-customizer:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`
Then launch it by typing:
`grub-customizer`

You will be presented with a window

- Click the [General settings tab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19905635/StackExchange/grub2.png)
- Mark the [show menu, look for other operating systems and Boot default entry after XX Seconds](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19905635/StackExchange/grub4.png) toggle boxes. Click 'Save' (shown on the picture in red) then 'File' (shown in green) -> Install To MBR
- Close grub-customizer and restart your computer

Comment: I type in "sudo apt-get install grub-customizer " hit enter.command works.but it asks for my password and it wont let me type it in.I am sure this is do to my inexperience with Ubuntu.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. For security purposes, the terminal neither shows you your password as it is typed, nor does it substitute the characters you type with stars '*'.

Just enter your password on the keyboard and press enter :)

Comment: Whoops, that's my fault.
Updating the answer with the fix.

Just follow the answer from the top again and it should work! :)

Comment: do i want "generate recovery entries" like yours aswell?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I neither know nor can I find any documentation on what 'generate recovery entries' does.

That being said, the two references that I could find about it both suggested that you do indeed want to generate recovery entries.

[source 1](http://www.linuxinsider.com/story/75243.html)

[source 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166364&page=3)

Comment: thx so much for your help,It works great!